# Windows 10 Horizontal Scroll Issue

Tags: windows-10, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'd like to know What this thing is and how to disable it if possible. It only appears in windows with a horizontal scroll-bar and it allows you to scroll left-right with the mouse wheel. I've tried googling but I can't seem to find out what this is even called.

[image]